# Playwright arbitrary failures with Astro SSR

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright, astrojs

I have a simple astro component that has this structure:

```js
---
import CreateProjectContainer from "../components/CreateProject/CreateProjectContainer";
import ProjectList from "../components/ProjectList";
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
---

<Layout title="HeatmapHub">
  <main class="m-4 flex flex-col justify-center gap-5 items-center">
    <ProjectList client:load />
    <CreateProjectContainer client:load />
  </main>
</Layout>
```

`CreateProjectContainer` is an interactive component that has a button which performs an action (hide and show another component).

When developing e2e test with Playwright, I have faced a problem that I think it's caused by Astro SSR. The following test fails arbitrary, because clicks the button before being interactive.

```js
test('Create a new project', async ({ page }) => {
  const newProjectName = 'My new project'
  await page.goto('/')

  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add new Project' }).click()
  await page.getByLabel('Project Name').fill(newProjectName)
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Confirm project creation' }).click()

  await expect(
    page.getByRole('heading', { name: newProjectName })
  ).toBeVisible()
})
```

`client:load` is the fastest option that Astro gives to make components interactives. Also, I don't want to make the component not support just to make my test pass.

I have found a solution that implies to wait for the 'networkidle' when navigating to the page, but it's not recommended in [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-goto-option-wait-until)

```js
await page.goto('/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' })
```

Another option would be to disable Astro SSR for testing if possible, but I don't think this will be good since tests will be testing a non-final situation.